# disable rollup tree shake for web-component

Tags: typescript, web-component, rollup, tree-shaking

I have a typescript file that import a web-component.
when I import my web component like below it works fine without problem:

```
import 'jb-input';
const elem:any = document.querySelector('#username')
```

but in typescript, I have to set my `elem` type to web component Class type so i import its class

```
import {JBInputWebComponent} from 'jb-input';
const elem:JBInputWebComponent = document.querySelector('#username')
```

in this case, my input web component stop working and the rollup tree shake the entire script file because it think I don't use its code but the web component needs to be defined in HTML context in its own file.
question is what can I do in my web component or ts file or rollup to stop tree-shaking web component file?

Comment: Don't have time to test this (so I'm not posting it as an answer) but do both. `import 'jb-input'; import {JBInputWebComponent} from 'jb-input';`

Comment: @JaredSmith your answer is correct and I tried it so you can post it but I hope I could find a better way

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rollup will tree-shake unused code, and it does so on the *Javascript*, not the *Typescript*, meaning that if the import is *only really* used by Typescript and it has side-effects (like calling `document.registerElement`) then you will not get the result you want. Rollup however *does* understand this:

```typescript
import 'some_module';
```

To mean that the import is for side-effects and it won't shake out that code, so you can just do both in your code:

```typescript
import 'some_module';
import { SomeWebComponent } from 'some_module';

const component: SomeWebComponent | null = document.querySelector('#username');
```

Note the `| null` on the type, you do have to account that `document.querySelector` and the other DOM methods may return null if they don't find the thing you want.